# Remote connection to SQL server 2008 sp2

Tags: sql-server

I built a window application in visual studio 2010. It is working fine at my computer.

if i have a pc that works with windows server 2008 and i install a sql server on it , how to make my application connect to database in the sql server that instaled in the server pc .

my pc connected to the server domain .

thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what piece of this problem you're having trouble with, so it is difficult to answer the question; is your application already talking to a database installed on your local PC?  If so, Sql Express?  Are you already familiar with installing and configuring Sql Server, including Windows Firewall, sql logins, etc, to enable remote connectivity?  Are you just looking for help in crafting the connection string?

Comment: the problem is what is the connection string req to connect my application with database in sql server express of another computer in the same network but that computer is a windows server computer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your application is already configured to use a Sql connection string, you'll just need to configure it for the Sql Server instance you're connecting to.

For example, if your database is called `MyDatabase`, and your windows server on your domain is called `myserver.local`, and you've installed Sql Express with the default `SQLEXPRESS` instance name, you could create your connection string (assuming ADO.NET) something like this:

```
Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=myserver.local\SQLEXPRESS
```

This configuration would be for Windows Authentication (Integrated Security=true): so your domain user accounts would need to be granted `LOGIN` rights on the server, and those Logins associated with `USERS` and `ROLES` in your database.  If you wanted to use Sql Logins instead (generally requires extra configuration when setting up your Sql Server), there are different connection strings settings for specifying username and passwords.  There are many options available for the connection strings as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx.  However, with Windows Authentication the only 3 you absolutely need are the ones shown above.

You can test connectivity to your Sql Server from your PC on the network using Sql Server Management Studio, which will enable you to verify the instance name and the authentication is working as expected if you can connect to the database.